# How to get image path and image url in spree based application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, spree

I am new to ruby on rails.I am using spree based appliacation.I am trying to get path of images for particular products but showing error "undefined method image_path".where am I doing wrong?

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
 def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << [ "image1" ]
    all.each do |pro|

      var = Spree::Variant.find_by(product_id: pro.id)        
       csv << [  "#{var.images.pluck(image_path(:attachment_file_name)).join(',')}" ]
    end
  end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `pluck`, there is no need for image_path.

```
"#{var.images.pluck(:attachment_file_name).first}"
```

That will get you the path to the image. Added `.first` so you only get the string.